# Unable to get current element id in callback of magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <div class="speaker">
        <a id="performer1"  class="html-popup" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/performer-detail.php">                    </a> 
</div>
```

I have this anchor tag on whose click popup will open.Id of the anchor needs to be passed dynamically in the following js in place of `#performer1`

```
 jQuery('.speaker a').click(function(e){
            var currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        })
        jQuery('.speaker a').magnificPopup({type: 'ajax',
            callbacks: {
              parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                // mfpResponse.data is a "data" object from ajax "success" callback
                // for simple HTML file, it will be just String
                // You may modify it to change contents of the popup
                // For example, to show just #some-element:
                mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#performer1');

                // mfpResponse.data must be a String or a DOM (jQuery) element

                console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
              },
              ajaxContentAdded: function() {
                // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
                console.log(this.content);
              }
            }
        });
```

i use following code to get the id of the `<a>` on its click

```
 jQuery('.speaker a').click(function(e){
                var currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            })
```

but how do i pass this currentID

Comment: Don't do `$(this).attr("id");`. It's a painful example of jQuery overuse. Just do `this.id`.

Comment: Seems like you ultimately just need to consult the documentation of whatever plugin this is you're using. Does it tell you how to access the `a` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code it may fix the problem

```
jQuery('.speaker a').magnificPopup({type: 'ajax',
        callbacks: {
          parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            // mfpResponse.data is a "data" object from ajax "success" callback
            // for simple HTML file, it will be just String
            // You may modify it to change contents of the popup
            // For example, to show just #some-element:
            var mp = $.magnificPopup.instance,
            t = $(mp.currItem.el[0]);

            var h=( t.data('custom') );

            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#'+h);

            // mfpResponse.data must be a String or a DOM (jQuery) element

            console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
          },
          ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
            console.log(this.content);
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first create variable using **window.currentID;** not inside the click event. make it as global

change click event function:

```
jQuery('.speaker a').click(function(e){
currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");

        })
```

and last change following line:

```
 mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#' +  currentID);
```

Comment: Why the nested quotes? That just breaks the selector.

Comment: it will store in currentID = '#currentID' not currentID = #currentID

Comment: I know. And that's broken. Why would a selector want single quotes around it?

Comment: in find() method  we need to pass id it require .find('#id') thats why.. its not element its id...

Comment: You're confusing the concept of JS string literal delimiters with the string's content. If you would bother to actually test a selector that looks like that, you'd see that it doesn't work.

Comment: You still need the `#`.  Just not the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1. Declare the variable `currentID` globally.
2. Replace `.find('#performer1')` by `.find('#'+currentID)`.

Here is the updated code.

```
var currentID;
jQuery('.speaker a').click(function(e) {
  currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
});
jQuery('.speaker a').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  callbacks: {
    parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
      // mfpResponse.data is a "data" object from ajax "success" callback
      // for simple HTML file, it will be just String
      // You may modify it to change contents of the popup
      // For example, to show just #some-element:
      mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#' + currentID);

      // mfpResponse.data must be a String or a DOM (jQuery) element

      console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
    },
    ajaxContentAdded: function() {
      // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
      console.log(this.content);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What if the user clicks a different link before the response comes back?

Comment: @Vishnu: And now you just broke his selector too. But then he did approve it, so it's just a WTF all around.

Comment: @squint: Please mention the problem with selector.

Comment: Thanks @squint, for pointing out the mistake. Cleared my doubt as well. Changed the answer back to original. :)